# Receive RenderedNameAttribute from HtmlInputRadioButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, properties, custom-controls

Actually I'm using an `aspx custom radiobutton control` like this

```
<input type="radio" id="declarableYes" value="Ja" name="declarable" class="form-radio" runat="server" required />
```

and i need to recieve the 'RenderedNameAttribute' which looks like this:

```
<input value="Ja" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolderMain$plcZones$lt$zoneMain$LegalData$declarable" type="radio" id="declarableYes" required="">
```

For exampel a asp.net 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlSelect' i can easely get the renderd `Name` attribute through the property `controlXy.Name` but for the RadioButton i can only access the "NonRendert" name which is in my case `declarable`.

[image]

I mentioned the `Non-Public members` where i can find the `RenderedNameAttribute` but i'm not abel to delegate to this property.

[image]

I need this value for javascript purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [**UniqueID**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.uniqueid(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

from **MSDN**:

> This property differs from the ID property, in that the UniqueID
>   property includes the identifier for the server control's naming
>   container.

***page.aspx***

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <uc1:ucRadioButton runat="server" ID="ucRadioButton" />
    </div>
</form>
```

***ucRadioButtons.ascx***

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ucRadioButton.ascx.cs" Inherits="ucRadioButton" %>

<input type="radio" id="declarableYes" value="Ja" name="declarable" class="form-radio" runat="server" required />
```

Which will result in

[image: UniqueID vs. ClientID]

hth

Comment: This was my first aproch. But im working with two radio buttons with the same render names. It is important to get the rendert name and not the uniqueID

Answer (score 0):

When you're dealing with ASP.NET all your server controls get's a very wierd name indeed, but there are solutions where you don't need to have this special id.

In JavaScript, you can request the ClientID, of the control which would do what you want.

For example, when you have the following control:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtName" runat="server" />
```

And in javascript, you want to alert this control, you could do something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<%= txtName.ClientID %>');
</script>
```

This should alert the control itself.

When you want a textbox named "txtName" have the name "txtName" even in your source, you could declare it like the following:

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtName" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

For more information about the ClientIDMode, please check the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation.

Comment: ClientIDMode affects the ID, which is already done in my solution. And in my case i'm not able to alter the JS script

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:

I wasn't able to find a buid-in solution to get this property. So i made a workaround for this by creating an extension for the `HtmlInputRadioButton` which takes the `UniqeID` and replaces the ID - ending with the name of the radio button.

Code:

```
public static string GetRenderedName(this System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputRadioButton radioButton)
{
    return radioButton.UniqueID.Replace(radioButton.ID, radioButton.Name);        
}
```